# Implementing Google Adsense with Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adsense, ruby-on-rails-6

I have followed the advice on the google adsense website instructing me to add the following code within the  tag of my pages.

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-64xxxxxxxxxxx" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

I have implemented this by adding it to my application.html.erb file.

Having deployed this to Heroku when I first load the page I get the following console error:

```
googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?guci=1.2.0.0.2.2.0.0&client=ca-pub-64xxxxxxxx Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

I suspect that I may have to wait for the ads to start propagating despite having a validated site but I have a second problem:

Then after navigating to a different page on my site I get:

```
adsbygoogle.js:72 Uncaught P {message: "adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one AdSense head tag supported per page. The second tag is ignored.", name: "TagError", pbr: true, stack: "TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one AdSen…lesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:238:39"}
```

I haven't duplicated the code in my  tag but I was wondering if this was a feature of turbolinks.

My site is verified and I have enabled auto ads but I think there is problem relating to my implementation. Does anyone have experience of implementing google ads in Rails 6 applications with turbolinks 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 403 Issue

I think you are right. It takes time to propagate. If it persists over couple of days - then there is something else. Are you still getting this error?

#### `Only one AdSense head tag supported per page` error

ThIt might be related to some framework feature, yes. But this error is harmless overall, it doesn't affect serving of ads. When you say "navigating to a different page" - do you know if it reloads the page or just updates html without reloading? If it's the latter then when the framework fetches second page and renders it - it's likely that page also has an `adsbygoogle.js` tag. Given that page is not reloaded - the old `adsbygoogle.js` tag is still loaded and you get this error.

Comment: Turned out the reason it was taking its time to propagate was because I had entered the url as .com rather than .co.uk You are right though that the other error is harmless. Thanks